# Hide last empty section header/footer in UITableView

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

Is there any way to hide last section? 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

just return 0 from

`- tableView:heightForFooterInSection:`

and/or

`- tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:`

when `section` is the section number you want to hide

Comment: it not does help. i think, because this footer of non-exist section

Answer (score 0):

You Can write Condition Like This :
in

`-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section`

```
if (indexPath.section ==sectionArray.count-1)
    {
        //you can set height of header.. 
    }
```